# Cannot install Drupal 8 on Windows 8 XAMPP PHP 5.6

Tags: 8, installation

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception

[image]

Cannot install D8 in latest XAMPP workstation on Win8. Can install D7 though.

I did increase `max_allowed_packet = 64M`

Comment: Please retitle this issue. Is xdebug running? There have been some problems with xdebug settings and D8.

Comment: Retitle with what and does it need to run xdebug or not?

Comment: It doesn't work with both enabled or disabled XDebug.

Comment: May be you have to do something with database. Can you check apache error log? I ran the installation without any issue just a couple of minutes ago on lamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have comments disabled in your opcache configuration. Add the following line

`opcache.save_comments=1` in php.ini or if `opcache` has its own config file

Please consult [this](https://drupal.org/node/2421451) for more details.